# Solutions of $((a-1)!)^x=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

I have an equation that I couldn't solve. I will be glad if you help me to do it.

Are there solutions in:
$((a-1)!)^x=0,$ with $a\in\mathbb N?$

Because with my knowledge in math, I found no solutions.

Comment: If $x=0$ the LHS equals $1$ which clearly does not equal $0$. If $x\not=0$ you can raise each side to $1/x$ which gives $(a-1)!=0$ which is never true since factorials are always at least $1$. So yeah, no solution, assuming $x$ is a real number.

Comment: Probably even easier is the fact that for any nonzero value $h\in\mathbb{R}$, the function $f(x)=h^x$ has no roots (in $\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n!\geq 1 \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb N$$

Substituting $n$ with $n-1$ does not change this fact, so your equation simplifies to $g^x = 0$, with $g \in \mathbb N$. There does not exist an $x$ value in $ \mathbb R$ (and I am nearly confident there does not exist any value in $\mathbb C$ either, but perhaps I am mistaken) that satisfies that equation, so you are correct in saying there are no solutions given your guidelines.

Edit: I am now fully confident (and backed up by Joe's comment) that there does not exist an $x \in \mathbb C$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: You are not mistaken. $a^b$, for real $a>0$, can be defined to be $\exp(b \log(a))$, where $\log(a)$ is the real logarithm of $a$. The range of the exponential function does not include zero, so if $a>0$ there is no solution $b$ for $a^b = 0$. Actually, even if $a$ is complex, and $a^b$ is "multi-valued", it is still defined in terms of the exponential function if $a \ne 0$.

Comment: @Joe I have learned to have little confidence in my mathematical reasoning in the dead of night, but in retrospect, that is indeed how exponents work.

Comment: I don't have too much confidence in my reasoning in the middle of the day, so I'm always expecting someone to catch some mistake I made, and I'm prepared to take it as a learning experience.